# how to get the following select statement to work

Tags: php

I have the following select tag in my form but when trying to process the form, only the second method and not the first. I thought that both should work?I am not sure what else to include here but have tried both methods but I think it could be the case that I am using the select option here... I actually thought that both methods should work and it should be the same... In all my previous pages, I used the latter coding but just have been thinking about this and shouldn't both be the same?

```
1) <?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header("Location: index.php?update_profile_process=error");
    exit();
}  else {
    $update_profile = strip_tags($_POST['update_profile']);
    $first_name = strip_tags($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = strip_tags($_POST['last_name']);
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);




    if ($update_profile === $first_name) {
        header("Location: update_profile_firstname.php");
         exit();
    } else {
        if ($update_profile === $last_name) {
             header("Location: update_profile_lastname.php");
             exit();
        } else {
            if ($update_profile === $username) {
                header("Location: update_profile_username.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                if ($update_profile === $email) {
                    header("Location: update_profile_email.php");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    if ($update_profile === $password) {
                    header("Location: reset.php");
                   exit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

2) <?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header("Location: index.php?update_profile_process=error");
    exit();
}  else {
    $update_profile = strip_tags($_POST['update_profile']);
    $first_name = strip_tags($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = strip_tags($_POST['last_name']);
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);



    if ($update_profile === 'first_name') {
        header("Location: update_profile_firstname.php");
         exit();
    } else {
        if ($update_profile === 'last_name') {
             header("Location: update_profile_lastname.php");
             exit();
      etc
```

I have this form in another page though but I have passed the variables through and thought that the above should work with the $ variables

```
<form class="signup-form" action="update_profile_process.php" method="POST">
       <select name="update_profile">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Which information would you like to update?</option> 
          <option value="first_name">First Name</option>
          <option value="last_name">Last Name</option>
          <option value="username">Username</option>
          <option value="email">E-mail</option>
          <option value="password">Password</option>
         </select>[enter image description here][1]
         <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?php echo $csrf; ?>">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Update Student's Information!</button>
   </form>
```

Comment: There are a few things you'd want to check when posting a question: 1. Have your tried something? 2. Do you have an error recorded. 3. Do you have an expected output? If you have these in your question it makes everything a lot simpler.

Comment: what's the data `$update_profile` and `$first_name` holds? do `var_dump()` for both and show us what you got

Comment: piano0011  by looking your form you are only sending `csrf` value to your php page. Apart from that nothing goes. Also selectbox doesn't have `name` attribute so it's values is not submitted. Also you are confused that if you select and value from select box it will go directly after submitting the form, which actually never happen.

Comment: but I do have a select name ... I guess I don't have an option name and that is why I can't use the post variables for my option tags... correct?

Comment: @piano0011  if you want to submit any data from form then it needs to has `name` attribute. As well as options never got submitted, only selected option value got submitted. Don't get confused.

Comment: thanks.. but for some reason I could still echo $first_name though.... I think this is weird

Comment: You are trying to access POST parameters that don’t even exist. What you actually want to do, is compare the submitted `update_profile` value with _text literals_, to determine which file to include. `if ($update_profile === 'first_name')` etc.

Comment: but the strange thing is that I can echo $first_name.... so I should be able to use it in comparison but I guess because $first_name is not an option name but option value

Answer (score 1):

Well looking at your code I can only conclude that the value in `$first_name` isn't 'first_name'.

Try to `var_dump()` or `echo` out the value for `$first_name` to confirm.

Comment: this seems to be a comment not an answer (since question is unclear right now)

Comment: I guess because I only have one actual name variable called subscription?

Comment: but I still could echo $first_name